# How to estimate the required sweeps to reach equilibrium in Ising model?

Tags: physics, montecarlo

How to estimate the required sweeps to reach equilibrium in 2D Ising model, considering the Metropolis algorithm.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with coding

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix This is a coding problem regarding Monte Carlo steps(sweeps) required to reach a certain state. You can find lots of questions of the Ising model on stackoverflow.

Comment: I think more appropriate venues would be [physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) or [mattermodeling.SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LluvioLiu please see [what question to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).